# Question concerning invariant distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let us consider the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with state space $I = \{0,1\}^m$ and transition probabilities  $$ p_{xy} = \begin{cases} m^{-1} &\mbox{if } \vert x - y \vert = 1 \\ 
0 & \mbox{otherwise } \end{cases}  $$

Here is $\vert x \vert = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \vert x_k \vert $.

I see the Markov chain as an $m$-dimensional unit hypercube and at each step from any vertex we have an equal probability of moving to any of the adjacent vertices.

The goal of this homework is to compute the invariant distribution of $X$. I know that we need the transition matrix and here I got stuck. I don't know how to assemble this matrix. Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: No idea what the invariant distribution could be without computing the transition probability matrix?

Comment: This means, the transition probability matrix isn't necessary in every case?

Comment: The invariant distribution should be as symmetric as the state space is...

Comment: Did you delete an earlier question? The phrase *I see the Markov chain as an $m$-dimensional unit hypercube and at each step from any vertex we have an equal probability of moving to any of the adjacent vertices* was my comment, and should make a stable distribution obvious, as @mjqxxxx has noted.  My other comment about periodicity is also important for this particular Markov chain.